# RequireJS & Toaster

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I have a problem implementing [Toaster](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster) into my demoApp which uses RequireJS. Here some code:

```
(function () {
    require.config({
        paths: {
            'angular': 'bower_components/angular/angular',
            'jquery': 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery',
            'toaster': 'bower_components/toaster/toaster'
        },
        shim: {
            angular: {
                deps: ['jquery'],
                exports: 'angular'
            },
            toaster: {
                deps: ['angular', 'jquery'],
                exports: 'toaster'
            }
        }
    });

    require([
        'angular',
        'app',
        'toaster',
        'jquery'
    ],
    function (angular, app, toaster) {
        'use strict';
        // toaster is undefined. I add it here just for a check. <<<<<<

        angular.bootstrap(angular.element('body')[0], ['myApp']);
    });
})();
```

This is main.js and toaster is `undefined` where I wrote the comment near the end. The file is loaded as I can see it at the Sources tab in the console. 
In addition, wherever I want to use `toaster`, it is `undefined`. Here some code from the same demo app:

First case:

```
define(['somefile', 'toaster'], function (someModule, toaster) {
    'use strict';

    // toaster is undefined

});
```

Second case ([John Papa Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md)):

```
define(['somefile', 'toaster'], function (someModule) {
    'use strict';

    someModule.controller('NewController', NewController);

    NewController.$inject = ['someDeps', 'toaster'];

    function NewController(someDeps, toaster) {

    // angular.js:13424 Error: [$injector:unpr] 
    // Unknown provider: toasterProvider <- toaster <- NewController

    }
});
```

Here's what I'm using:

```
Angular: 1.5.3
RequireJs: 2.2.0
Toaster: 2.0.0
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to distinguish between Angular modules and RequireJS modules. Toaster only registers an Angular module, no need to export anything *in a RequireJS way*.

```js
shim: {
  // ...
  toaster: {
    deps: ["angular", "jquery"]
  }
}
```

Bootstrapping:

```js
require(["angular", "app"], function (angular) {

  // here, app.js is loaded in the DOM, so you can bootstrap Angular:
  angular.bootstrap(angular.element("body")[0], ["myApp"]);

})
```

In your app.js:

```js
define(["toaster" /* , ... */], function () {

  // here, toaster.js is loaded in the DOM, so you can add the "toaster" Angular module in your Angular app dependencies:
  return angular.module("myApp", ["toaster" /* , ... */]);

});
```

Anywhere else:

```js
define(["app"], function (app) {

  // as myApp depends on toaster, you can inject the toaster service the Angular way:
  app.controller("MyController", ["toaster", function (toaster) {
    // ...
  }]);

});
```

Comment: Working as expected.